# Initialize member class that prohibits copy

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a member variable that is a class that prohibits copying (copy assignment operator is deleted). I want to make some checks to determine what to initiate the member to, thus I need to do this inside the constructor and not in and initializer list. It seem the member variable m is already initialed with the default constructor before entering the constructor of MyClass, then what is the point of the constructor... sorry for c++ rant.

Simple example:

```
class MyClass {
    NonCopy m;
    MyClass() {
        // Complex checks
        if(success) {
            m("success");
        else {
            m("failure");
        }

    }
```

The options I see is:

- Reside to dynamic allocation of m
- Relax copy prohibit requirement of m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the class has a valid copy or move constructor, or you are using C++17+, you can make a helper function that does the logic and then returns the correct object.  You then use that to initialize your member.  That would look like

```
class MyClass {
    NonCopy m;
    static NonCopy initialize_noncopy()
    {
        // Complex checks
        if(success) {
            return NonCopy("success");
        else {
            return NonCopy("faulure");
        }
    }
public:
    MyClass() : m(initialize_noncopy()) { }
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to move the decision part to a different function, but not the initialization. So, something like `MyClass() : m(decide() ? "success" : "failure") { }`

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Depends.  If you can't use C++17, or the class doesn't have a copy/move c'tor, then yes, that might be the way to go.  I try to avoid it though and try to put that logic into named functions.  Also, while the check in the example code is simple, the comment says *Complex checks* which most likely means in the OP's real code, a simple check like that might not be enough.  Hence, I show this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're supposed to initialize member variables *before* the constructor body

```
struct C {
    M member;
    C() : member("some arguments") { }
};
```

But this only works if you know the arguments for the member's initializer at that time! If you *really* don't want to initialize `member` until you get some more information in the constructor body, you can place it into a single-member anonymous `union`.

```
struct C {
    union { M member; };
    C() { // member is not initialized
        // do whatever
        new(&member) M("some arguments"); // explicitly initialize
    }
    // now you have to write all the other special functions!
    ~C() { member.~M(); }
    C(C const &x) = delete;
    C(C &&x) { new(&member) M(std::move(x.member)); }
    C &operator=(C const &x) = delete;
    C &operator=(C &&x) { member = std::move(x.member); return *this; }
};
```

Comment: I learned something new today!  I'll squirrel this nugget away as "I hope I never have code where I need to do this."  But if I do, now I know how to do it.