# C++ How to initialize const share_ptr<const obj> in constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers

I tried to use `const_cast` to get around this C++ problem but I am easily lost.

Basically the only way given to me to construct objects of type `B` is using the function `constructB` below. At the same time, I really need this behavior where the `_b` member of class `A` has to be a const pointer and the object it points to is not allowed to be modified.

Any ideas please?

EDIT : I cannot use the initializing list because I need to call constructB  first. Also the type `B` is a class type and not an `int`-like type

```
void constructB(int g, B& b){
    
//Construct b
//Note : This is the only way given to me to construct objects of type B

}
    
class A{
    
    const boost::shared_ptr<const B> _b;
    //In class A, _b is not allowed to change where it points to, and this _b is not allowed to be modified
    //I really need this behaviour
    public:
    A(int g){
    
        B b;
        constructB(g, b);
        //How can I initialize _b with b here?
    }
    
}
```

Comment: members are not initialized in the constructors body. You cannot assign to it, but you can initialize it (before the constructor runs).

Comment: I cannot use the initializing list because I need to call `constructB ` first

Comment: @sigma1988 This is what a helper function is for.  kind of like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242526/initialize-member-class-that-prohibits-copy/66242637#66242637

Comment: you can still use the initializer list. Write a function that returns the newly constructed `B` and use that in the initializer list

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not think this is right dup

Comment: your edit doesn't change question or answer much. The place to initialize members is the initializer list and you can use it here too

Comment: Right indeed, thanks!!! very helpful

Comment: @Slava It the one I found too, though I agree that its not the best duplicate

Comment: @Slava Target changed.  Should be better now.

Comment: You cannot make `std::shared_pointer` to point to local object, you need to initialize it using `std::make_shared` and then pass to `constructB(g, b);`

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not think so, OP has to use strange "construct" function that accepts "constructed" object by reference. I doubt there is such duplicate :)